# Scaling background image with css only cuts it off, doesn't change the scale

Tags: html, image, css, width

I'm trying to scale down a background image with css.  My browser has it scaled all the way to it's maximum resolution, and nothing that should work, is working.

When I try and use `max-width` it doesn't scale the image, it only cuts off the right edge of the image, and it stays at the same scale.

Here's my CSS

```
.proj-header{ /* Settings for projects bgr image */
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20;
    height: 450;
    background-image: url(pics/fight_shy_lot.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position: 50% 38%;
    max-height: 40%;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;

}
```

I don't think html is important as it's just an empty div.  Everything is in the css.

The only thing I could get to work is `background-size`, but it lead to issues when the viewport is resized from my base res.

So my questions is why isn't `max-width` doing what everyone says it should be doing, or am I using it wrong?

I'm pretty new to web design so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I searched all over for an answer, and all people say is to use `max-width`, which doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: Have you tried  the background-size property?

Comment: Yeah, like I mentioned in my post, that worked to an extent, but it introduced a lot of issues when I resized the window, so I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: Background-size is the way to go. Max-width has little to do with it. Could you describe in more detail what problems you encountered with using background-sze? I see no viewport-changing problems on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images) in the sections about cover and contain.

Comment: max-width limits the width of a container, it is not related to the size of a background image. Backgrounds can be larger, smaller than their container, or different aspect ratio. Please state precisely what you want to achieve

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response.  I'm trying to keep the container the same size while scaling the image down within it.  Everything I googled said to use max-width, but I guess that's not the case for what I'm trying to achieve? Thanks for the replys.